# python 2.7 find in list fails, but iterating over list finds it

Tags: list, python-2.7, member

My day for asking for help.
I have a big list of strings, created from a 13225 line text file:

```
with open(dest_file) as f2:
    content_dest = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f2]
```

My search string is `mp`.
Checking for `mp` in the list fails. All items in the list are

```
<type str>
```

When I iterate over the list, `mp` is found.

I don't see anything obvious (again) why this is so.  I'm after a list index so I can mess with the data at index + something by accessing the indices I need in the big list.  Since my iterations 'work', I guess my question is how do I get the 'mp in list' code to actually work..?  And/or why doesn't `mp` in list' work??  Many thanks.

```
mp = 'r1_crvR_2_29040_-8580_180'
chk = mp in content_dest
print '**', chk

for x in content_dest:
    chk = mp in x
    if chk:
        print 'Found:', mp, x
        print type(mp), type(x)

for i in range(0, len(content_dest)):
    chk = mp in content_dest[i]
    if not chk:
        pass
    else:
        print 'Found:', mp, content_dest[i], i
```

results in:

```
** False
Found: r1_crvR_2_29040_-8580_180       Name "r1_crvR_2_29040_-8580_180"
<type 'str'> <type 'str'>
Found: r1_crvR_2_29040_-8580_180       Name "r1_crvR_2_29040_-8580_180"  11846
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mp in list
```

this works as: to check if string is in list.
As I can understand from the code above, you have only one line in the file with the requested substring. This line is:

`Name "r1_crvR_2_29040_-8580_180"`

for easier understanding I'll show you another example:

```
my_list = ["abc"]
check = 'a' in my_list
```

what should be the result of `check`?
False, sure, because we have no this string, `a` in our list.
To verify if there is some strings which consists of our string we can do:

```
double_check = any(['a' in x for x in my_list])
```

double_check will show us if there is some string in our list which consists of the requested string.

Comment: Thanks!  So if I understand from both answers, my code fails because the string I'm looking for is a substring in the list.  Checking each item works because.. well, it just does.  So I should use that method.  Wish I could flag both answers right.

Comment: As you wish!The main idea is to help, not to get a flag :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference searching in a list or in the items of a list.

For example,`a`is not in the list:

```
>>> L = ['abc', 'xyz']
>>> 'a' in L
False
```

but it is in one item of the list:

```
>>> for x in L:
...     if 'a' in x:
...        print 'found'
... 
found
```

Here:

```
>>> 'a' in L
```

is equivalent to:

```
chk = mp in content_dest
```

and your loop to the loop above.